# Emu8086 - Conditional printing doesn't break

Tags: assembly, emulation, emu8086

so this is my problem, whenever i press 'a' and it meets the condition it prints the text that is under 'a:' and then prints text in 'b:' too. how do i break each other in different condition? thanks :)

```
cmp byte ptr [temp+2], 'a'      ;condition
je a  

cmp byte ptr [temp+2], 'b'      ;condition
je b

a:
mov dx, offset msgA             ;land
mov ah, 09
int 21h 

b:
mov dx, offset msg14            ;water
mov ah, 09
int 21h 


ret                                   
msgA db 10, 13, "                           Land:$"
msg14 db 10, 13, "                           Water:$"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the behavior you coded. It just falls through from `a:` to `b:`. So just add `jmp`s to the end and it will work as desired.

```
cmp byte ptr [temp+2], 'a'      ;condition
je a  

cmp byte ptr [temp+2], 'b'      ;condition
je b
jmp finish                      ; --- add this for the case, that neither 'a' nor 'b' was the input

a:
mov dx, offset msgA             ;land
mov ah, 09
int 21h 
jmp finish                      ; --- JMP to the end - do not fall through

b:
mov dx, offset msg14            ;water
mov ah, 09
int 21h 
jmp finish                      ; --- JMP to the end - in this case not necessary, but just in case you'd add more cases

finish:
ret
```

Answer (score 0):

The program flow continues after your `int 21h` instruction - in your case, that is the code at the `b:` label. If you do not want that, you need to jump to a different address after the `int` instruction is done:

```
...
a:
    mov dx, offset msgA         ; land
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h 
    jmp done                    ; program continues here after the `int` instruction

b:
    mov dx, offset msg14        ; water
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h 

done:
    ret
...
```

Since all you do when you are done is returning from the procedure, you could also simply use a `ret` instead of the `jmp`.

Answer (score 0):

A label is not a barrier; it's just a name for some location in the program that allows convenient access to said location.

As always if you want to alter the control flow, use some sort of branching instruction, e.g.:

```
a:
mov dx, offset msgA             ;land
mov ah, 09
int 21h 
jmp done

b:
mov dx, offset msg14            ;water
mov ah, 09
int 21h 

done:
```